Boundary terms in the gravitational action
A correct derivation of Einstein's field equations from an action principle $\delta I=0$ is given in

Poisson, E. (2004). A Relativist’s Toolkit: The Mathematics of Black-Hole Mechanics. Cambridge University Press.
Parattu, K., Chakraborty, S. and Padmanabhan, T. (2016) “Variational principle for gravity with null and non-null boundaries: A unified boundary counter-term.” Eur. Phys. J. C, Vol. 76, No. 3, p. 129.

and sketched out in

Padmanabhan, T. (2010) Gravitation Foundations and Frontiers. Cambridge University Press.
Wald, R. M. (1984). General Relativity. The University of Chicago Press.

In a nutshell, the Hilbert action $I_{EH}=\int R\sqrt{-g}\,d^4x$ is amended by adding another term (the Gibbons-Hawking-York boundary term) $I_b$ which cancels the boundary term arising from the variation of $I_{EH}$ when the integral is over a compact 4D volume.
Poisson adds a third term $I_0$ which does not affect the equations of motion, but accounts for the fact that the action $I_b$ is infinite when calculated over an unbounded region of flat spacetime; hence, $I_0$ cancels the 'infinity' in $I_b$ for unbounded integrals in asymptotically flat spacetime.
Two well-known texts appear to ignore this issue completely. Weinberg simply says "integrating over all space..." the boundary terms drop out. (Does he mean 3D space or 4D spacetime?) Landau-Lifshitz specify "integrating over all space between two fixed time coordinates $x_0$" the boundary terms drop out.
I have two questions:

Are Weinberg and Landau-Lifshitz simply wrong to dismiss the boundary term with a hand-waive? Assuming the distribution of matter in the universe is not infinite, then it seems to be true that as $|\bf{x}|\rightarrow\infty$ the metric is asymptotically flat. (Are all spacetimes asymptotically flat?) But this isn't true for $|t|\rightarrow\infty$. So is Landau-Lifshitz correct in saying "integrate over all space between two fixed time coordinates $x_0$". If you consider a 4D "cylinder" with $T_1 < t < T_2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2<R$, it's easy to show that the surfaces $t = \text{constant}$ contribute nothing to the boundary term (although Landau-Lifshitz do not develop any of the machinery that Poisson does to derive the GHY boundary term).

Poisson's extra term $I_0$ patches up the hole in the GHY term $I_b$ but only for asymptotically flat spacetimes. Again, are all spacetimes asymptotically flat?



Obviously, not all spacetimes are asymptotically flat. Our universe is not asymptotically flat (we believe). The boundary terms mentioned by Poisson are likely not relevant to what Weinberg and LL are trying to study. It makes no sense to introduce unnecessary ideas and concepts if and when they are not relevant to the immediate goals of the project.
